SQL Server merge performance
Performing a merge against a table with 40 million rows takes many hours, on a database server with significant horsepower (64 GB memory, 16 cores).
I load data into a staging table via SqlBulkCopy, and then MERGE into a target table. The MERGE is performed in batches to minimize impact on TempDb.
The gist of my statement is:
DECLARE @RowID int = 0,
        @RowCount int,
        @Batches int = 0,
        @BatchSize int = 10000

SELECT @RowCount = COUNT(1) 
FROM [someStagingTable]

WHILE @RowID <= @RowCount 
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO [someTargetTable] AS Target
    USING (SELECT * FROM [someStagingTable] 
           WHERE ID BETWEEN @RowID AND @RowID + @BatchSize - 1) AS Source
              ON Target.AccountNumber = Source.AccountNumber

    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE 
            SET ...

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT ...

    SET @RowID = @RowID + @BatchSize
    SET @Batches = @Batches + 1
 
    COMMIT
END

Regarding indexing:

[someStagingTable].ID is an int identity column with a clustered index
[someTargetTable].AccountNumber is indexed


I suggest that you check to see what the clustered index key is for your target table. If different from AccountNumber, it might be advantageous to perform a lookup in advance, add the clustered index value to your staging table, and then join on that during the merge. It also may be advantageous to assign staging ID values ordered by that clustered index value. This can reduce page references during the merge step, ad adjacent keys may reside on the same or adjacent pages. Both techniques increase preprocessing overhead, but can improve efficiency of each batched merge operation.

Without seeing the query plan and the full table/index definitions this is not answerable.

In this particular case, despite the presence of an obvious index on [someTargetTable].AccountNumber, the MERGE statement needed an index hint:
MERGE INTO [someTargetTable] WITH (INDEX=IX_someTargetTableAccountNumber) AS Target
  USING (SELECT * FROM [someStagingTable] WHERE ID BETWEEN @RowID AND @RowID + @BatchSize - 1) AS Source
  ON Target.AccountNumber = Source.AccountNumber

This became obvious when inspecting the SQL execution plan, which started with a TABLE SCAN of [someTargetTable] in each batch. Adding the index hint reduced the execution time of each batch from ~300 seconds to ~1 second. The execution plan shifts from a TABLE SCAN to an INDEX SEEK, dropping rows read from 40M to 10K (the batch size).

Is it an Index Seek followed by a Lookup now? That's could well be worse.
